Convergence of regular subsequence implies convergence of sequence?
Edit: Assume all sequences are decreasing.
In probability theory we have for a integer valued, non-negative random variable $X$ that
$$ EX = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X \geq n). $$
Now if for some $K>0$ fixed, $\sum_{n\geq 1} P(X\geq Kn) < \infty$, then this implies $EX = KE(X/K) < \infty $. My question is, does this hold for a general sequence? Suppose we have a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ non-negative. let $\varphi(n) = Kn + r$, define a regular subsequence such that $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_{\varphi(n)}$ converges . Does this imply that $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n < \infty$?
In the other words, does $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n = \infty$ imply that the sum of every regular subsequence diverges? I know that this is true when $a_n = 1/n$, since
$$\frac{1}{K} + \frac{1}{2K}+\ldots = \frac{1}{K} ( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots) = \infty,$$
and we can use this fact along with the comparision test to show that the sum of $1/(Kn+r)$ also divereges.

First of all, you want to assume $X$ takes integer values.  Not every discrete random variable does.
As for your questions, of course the answer is no.  Consider the sequence $$a_n = \cases{1/n & if $n$ is odd\cr  0 & if $n$ is even}$$
On the other hand, it is true if your sequence is decreasing.
EDIT:
If $a_n$ is decreasing, $a_{Kn+i} \le a_{Kn+r}$ for $r \le i < r+K$ while $a_{Kn+i} \ge a_{Kn+r}$ for $r-K < i \le r$, so (if $0 \le r < K$)
$$ K \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{Kn+r} \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=r}^{r+K-1} a_{Kn+i} = \sum_{m=K+r}^\infty a_m$$
while
$$ K \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{Kn+r} \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{i=r-K+1}^r a_{Kn+i} = \sum_{m=K+r+1}^\infty a_m$$
so the two series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{Kr+n}$ and
$\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_m$ either both converge or both diverge.

I edited the question to show that $X$ is integer valued. I originally had in mind a decreasing sequence, but I left that out for some reason. Is there a proof of these statements in the decreasing case?
